# Jquery tools Ajax login with Coldfusion, problem cancelling modal

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, modal-dialog, jquery-tools

I am testing an ajax  modal login using [Jquery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/)

Here's my test page.

```
   <cfparam name="session.auth.isLoggedIn" default="false">

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html> 

    <head> 
        <title>jQuery modal logon test</title> 
        <!-- include the Tools --> 
        <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 

        <!--- add styles --->
        <!--- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginbox.css" />  --->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.flowplayer.org/tools/css/standalone.css"/>   
            <style>
            /* error message */
.error {
    height:15px;
    background-color:#FFFE36;
    font-size:13px;
    border:1px solid #E1E16D;
    padding:4px 10px;
    color:#000;
    display:none;

    z-index: 9999;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px; 

    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ddd;    
}
.error p {
    margin:0;       
}

        .modal {
            background-color:#fff;
            display:none;
            width:350px;
            padding:15px;
            text-align:left;
            border:2px solid #333;

            opacity:0.8;
            -moz-border-radius:6px;
            -webkit-border-radius:6px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
        }

        .modal h2 {
            background:url(/img/global/info.png) 0 50% no-repeat;
            margin:0px;
            padding:10px 0 10px 45px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #333;
            font-size:20px;
        }
        </style>
    </head> 

    <body> 

    <p> 
        <div id="loginMenu">
        <cfif session.auth.isLoggedIn>
            <a href="logout.cfm">Log out</a>
        <cfelse>
            <a href class="modalInput" rel="#login">Login</a>
        </cfif>
        <a href class="modalInput" rel="#register">Register</a>
        </div> 
    </p> 

    <!-- user input dialog -->
    <cfif isDefined("session.auth.failedLogins")>
        <cfset loginMsg=#session.auth.failedLogins# & " failed logins">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset loginMsg="Please log in">
    </cfif>
    <div><em/></div>

    <div class="modal" id="login"> 
        <!-- login form --> 
        <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="loginMsg"><p><cfoutput>#loginMsg#</cfoutput></p></div>
        <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username..." title="Must be at least 8 characters." required="required" ></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password..." title="Try to make it hard to guess" required="required"></p>
        <p>
        <button type="submit"> Login </button> 
        <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
        </p>
        </form>
    </div> 

    <div  class="modal" id="register">
    <!-- signup form-->
        <form id="signupForm"  autocomplete="off" method="get" action=""  novalidate="novalidate">
        <CFSET structDelete(session, 'form')>
        <cfset session.form.validate_require="username|'Username' is a required field.;password|'Password' is a required field.;confirmpassword|'Confirm password' is a required field.;">


        <fieldset>
        <p>
        <label>username *<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username..." />     </label>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label>password *<br>
        <input type="password" name="password" required="required" minlength="6" placeholder="password..." /></label>       
        </p>
        <p>
        <label>confirm password *<br>
        <input type="password" name="confirmpassword"  data-equals="password" placeholder="password..."/></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
        </p>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({

        // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
        mask: {
            color: '#ebecff',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.9
        },

        closeOnClick: false,
        onClose: function () {
            $('.error').hide();
        }
    });

    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        var form = $(this);

            // submit with AJAX
            $.getJSON("/yourGPpractice/cfcs/security.cfc?method=testSignup&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column&" + form.serialize(), function(json) {

                // everything is ok. (server returned true)
                if (json === true)  {
                    // close the overlay
                    triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
                    $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");

                // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
                } else {
                    var tempString
                    tempString = "<p>" + json + " failed logins</p>"
                    $("#loginMsg").html(tempString);

                }
            });

            // prevent default form submission logic
            e.preventDefault();

    }); 


    // initialize validator and add a custom form submission logic
    $("#signupForm").validator().submit(function(e) {

        var form = $(this);

        // client-side validation OK.
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

            // submit with AJAX
            $.getJSON("/yourGPpractice/cfcs/security.cfc?method=testSignup&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column&" + form.serialize(), function(json) {

                // everything is ok. (server returned true)
                if (json === true)  {
                    // close the overlay
                    triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
                    $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");

                // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
                } else {
                    form.data("validator").invalidate(json);
                }
            });

            // prevent default form submission logic
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $.tools.validator.fn("[minlength]", function(input, value) {
        var min = input.attr("minlength");

        return value.length >= min ? true : {     
            en: "Please provide at least " +min+ " character" + (min > 1 ? "s" : ""),
        };
    });

    $.tools.validator.fn("[data-equals]", "Value not equal with the $1 field", function(input) {
        var name = input.attr("data-equals"),
             field = this.getInputs().filter("[name=" + name + "]"); 
        return input.val() == field.val() ? true : [name]; 
    });

    });
    </script> 

    </body> 

    </html>
```

security.cfc contains the following method

```
<cffunction name="testSignup" access="remote" returnType="any" output="false">
    <cfset var validationVar= structNew()>
    <cfset validationVar = true>
    <cfreturn validationvar>
</cffunction>
```

In Firebug I can see the return is 'true' and on my dummy login the loginmenu div correctly changes to 'logout'. However, this happens under the modal layer which is not cancelled.

triggers.eq(0).overlay().close(); correctly closes the modal for the login form, but does not cancel the overlay for the registration form, though the line following does correctly change the 'loginmenu' div to log out, *under* the modal. Whats going on?

This is infuriating.

```
        // everything is ok. (server returned true)
        if (json === true)  {
            // close the overlay
            alert("about to close the overlay!");
            triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
            $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");
```

the alert is displayed but the triggers.eq(0).overlay().close(); doesn't??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, in `$("#signupForm").validator().submit(function(e) {`

```
// close the overlay
triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();
```

ie reference the second overlay trigger as 2 items, javascript referencing starting at 0

Answer (score 0):

As simple as change `e.preventDefault();` with `return false;`

Comment: I tried replacing e.preventDefault() with return false at the bottom of the $("#signupForm").validator().submit(function(e) code block but no difference I'm afraid